# Route Not found error in Durandal child route

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, durandal, single-page-application, durandal-2.0

I am getting "route not found" when I try to use child routing.  To cover my bases, here is how the routing in the application is designed.

The main.js file contains routing for the top navigation and is done as-

```
                    router.map([
                        { route: 'LOC', moduleId: 'LOC', title: 'LC', nav: 3 }
                    ]);
```

I map routes for the footer of the page as-

```
        router.map('About', 'About', 'About', false);
    router.map('Help', 'Help', 'Help', false);
```

When a user clicks on the 'LOC' route created above, the left nav is displayed on that view.  That view uses the child routing and is set up as-

```
var childRouter = router.createChildRouter()
    .makeRelative({
        moduleId: 'viewmodels/',
        fromParent: true
    }).map([
                        { route: '*LCClientSearch', moduleId: 'LCClientSearch', title: 'Create LC', type: 'intro', hash: '#LCClientSearch', nav: true },
                        { route: '*LCPending', moduleId: 'LCPending', title: 'Pending LC', type: 'intro', hash: '#LCPending', nav: true }

    ]).buildNavigationModel();
```

LOC defaults to the LCClientSearch route and displays it correctly initially, HOWEVER, nothing right happens from that point on.  When the user clicks on LCClientSearh or LCPending, I get 'route not found' error.

LOC view-

```
     <div class="span2 well">
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li class="nav-header">Availability</li>

        <!--ko foreach: availability-->
        <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive }">
            <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, text: title"></a>
        </li>
        <!--/ko-->

        <li class="nav-header">Manual Post</li>


        <!--ko foreach: ManualPost-->
        <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive }">
            <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, text: title"></a>
        </li>
        <!--/ko-->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Why do I get route not found?

Comment: I think the moduleId in your child router should be 'LOC' not viewmodels.

Comment: @nimgrg I changed the moduleid, but still does not work.  When the page first loads, it actually loads LCClientSearch view fine. So, it is finding the child route when the page loads, it is just that the navigation does not work when clicking on the child route links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect its because your parent route doesn't have a splat - [check out the documentation for child routers](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router.html#child-routers). Try changing the route from the parent view to:

```
router.map([
    { route: 'LOC*details', moduleId: 'LOC', title: 'LC', nav: 3 }
]);
```

And then change the child routes to:

```
[
    { route: 'LCClientSearch', moduleId: 'LCClientSearch', title: 'Create LC', type: 'intro', nav: true },
    { route: 'LCPending', moduleId: 'LCPending', title: 'Pending LC', type: 'intro', nav: true }
]
```

That should then match the routes `LOC/LCClientSearch` and `LOC/LCPending` respectively.

Comment: Thanks!  You suspected right.  The only other addition I had to add was a hash in the parent (hash: '#LOC').

Comment: Hi @gerrod, First of all thanks for the answer. I've successfully implemented this, it work like a charms! But unfortunately when I try to navigate to the parent route (e.g: LOC) it will show me an message in console e.g: "Route Not Found LOC". Any help or suggestion would be appreciate. Thanks ! :)